# Android minifyEnabled option

Tags: android

Recently I have noticed the difference in android application behaviour as **minifyEnabled** option value changes. Assuming that by default **minifyEnabled** option is set to false.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}
```

The configuration above is the default configuration of my android project. At the time as the application is compiled everything is working fine.
However when the value of **minifyEnabled** is set to true, the application throws different exceptions and is not working properly. The one of the errors is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at b.c.a.a.d.i.a(:94)
        at b.c.a.a.d.b.a(Unknown Source:10)
        at b.c.a.a.d.j.onPostExecute(:36)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:696)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:180)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:713)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

What is more, I cannot notice the source of the exception. **(Unknown Source:10)**

When **minifyEnabled** is false, in similar situation there is no exception.
Could anyone explain why changing the value causes the application to not work properly.

*It does not matter whether the option is changed within the debug or release version*

Comment: Read https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`minifyEnabled` activates ProGuard or R8 (depending on Gradle plugin version) which attempts to trim unused code and obfuscate (rename) classes and methods. That's why you're seeing `at b.c.a.a.d.i.a(:94)` in your error stack.

In most cases this does not affect how your app works but there are some instances (usually when using reflection) where it causes errors. In those cases you have to manually add exceptions to the `proguard-rules.pro` files.

Read in detail on official page: [Shrink, obfuscate, and optimize your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code)